# Proj4Leaflet angular 5

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular5

I read different topic but it doesn't work.
I would like to use leaftlet and Proj4Leaflet for a projection espg in angular project

```
import * as L from 'Proj4Leaflet';
const crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:3006',
'+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs',
{
  resolutions: [
    8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128
  ],
  origin: [0, 0]
});

const myMap = L.map('map').setView([46.2, 2], 6);
myMap.options.crs = crs;
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
   attribution: 'My Map'
}).addTo(myMap);

this.http.get('../assets/data.json')
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  const lMyGeoJson = L.geoJSON(<any>data, <any>{
    style: function(feature, layer) {
      return {
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: '#66CC66'
      };
    }
  }).addTo(myMap);

  console.log(lMyGeoJson);
} );
```

The map don't display and i have an error in execution

> TypeError: L.map is not a function

Thanks per advance

Comment: You probably forgot to import `leaflet`.

Comment: I have the same issue of not quite knowing how import proj4leaflet and get it working, please do update if you resolve it, I will too!

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `@types/proj4leaflet` package as well. This contains the TypeScript declarations for the exported code of Proj4Leaflet.

```
// In package.json
...
"@types/proj4leaflet": "^1.0.5",
...
"proj4leaflet": "^1.0.2",
...

// In .angular-cli.json
"../node_modules/proj4leaflet/lib/proj4.js",
"../node_modules/proj4leaflet/src/proj4leaflet.js",

// In your app.module.ts
declare var require: any;
require('proj4leaflet');

// Importing in your .ts code
import {Map, Proj} from "leaflet";

// Creating the CRS:
let crs = new Proj.CRS(...);
```

**EDIT** still doesn't work for me though